# Lost ttyUSB0, Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such device or address

Tags: tty, serial-port, putty, minicom

Previously I used putty with ttyUSB0 to read the serial log in my SmartBox, but by accident I couldn't read it anymore and when I checked, my ttyUSB0 file on Ubuntu 18.04 was lost. I have tried to fix it like turning off the device's power saving mode and creating a new ttyUSB0 file but can't read or use Putty anymore, I also tried with minicom -s same error.

Here are some of my logs:

```
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6613 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 032: ID 18d1:4ee7 Google Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

thanhchung@Chung-Computer:~$ dmesg | tail
[20446.193851] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Amlogic
[20446.193854] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 1532940130B4B25
[20450.071398] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 31
[20450.491298] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[20450.648732] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee7, bcdDevice= 4.40
[20450.648734] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[20450.648735] usb 1-2: Product: oppen
[20450.648737] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Amlogic
[20450.648738] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 1532940130B4B25
[21086.578730] perf: interrupt took too long (3159 > 3138), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63250
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:~$
```

i create it using mknod /dev/ttyUSB0 c 180 0

```
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:~$  ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 188, 0 Thg 2 23 13:49 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

but it's still unusable

```
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:~$ sudo minicom 
[sudo] password for thanhchung: 
minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such device or address
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:~$
```

i have looked up and learned the methods in similar questions but can't find the solution for me, can anyone help me?